# firebase authenticating requests using service account with admin sdk

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-admin

I am trying to authenticate a server application from a third party using a token generated in my backend using the admin SDK with a service account. For testing purposes, I try to use Postman for the request. I did put the generated token in the header of the postman request by adding Authorization as a header key with the value being Bearer [token] .
Unfortunately, when looking in the Firebase log explorer I get the error:

> verifyIdToken() expects an ID token, but was given a custom token

This is the code for creating the token:

```
const admin = require("./firebaseInit");
const uid = "test";

const generateToken = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Validation logic
    const isValidService = true; // add more later(testing only)

    if (!isValidService) {
      return res.status(403).json({error: "Invalid service or application"});
    }

    // Set CORS headers
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://omnibill-twl.web.app");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");


    // Generate a token
    const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
    console.log("Custom Token:", customToken);
    res.json({oneTimeToken: customToken});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating one-time token:", error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Internal Server Error"});
  }
};

module.exports = {generateToken};
```

This is the code which is grabbing the token:

```
const authHeader = req.header("Authorization");
    const idToken = authHeader ? authHeader.split("Bearer ")[1] : null;
```

This is the line where it fails with the error:

```
// Verify the token
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
```

I tried inspecting the generated token on https://jwt.io/ and it states that the signature is invalid.
I don't know why because I use the admin sdk and that should automatically sign it with the private key from the JSON file I downloaded from Firebase after creating a new key.
I double-checked if the received key is the same as the one which is created and they are matching.
I am pretty new to Firebase and JS in general, so sorry if my description is lacking info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't use `verifyIdToken()` to validate a custom token, so what you're trying will never work.  That function is for validating user ID tokens coming from a web or mobile app where the user is signed in.

If you've generated a custom token for your user, you need to use that to sign in the user in your client app with Firebase Auth using `signInWithCustomToken()`, and after that, you can get an ID token for the user with `getToken()`.  Only that token you can pass to your backend and validate with `verifyIdToken()`.

Comment: Hey Doug,

thanks a lot for your help.
I was able to generate a custom token and verify it using the decoding function from jsonwebtoken.